# Rank after appending a column to a Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be the Vandermonde matrix

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&\cdots&1 \\
a_1&a_2&\cdots&a_N\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_1^{M-2}&a_2^{M-2}&\cdots&a_N^{M-2}\\
a_1^{M-1}&a_2^{M-1}&\cdots&a_N^{M-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also assume that the matrix is fat i.e. $N>M$ and that all $a_i$ are distinct. Now, I attach a column to this matrix to get $B$ which is:
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&\cdots&1&0 \\
a_1&a_2&\cdots&a_N&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_1^{M-2}&a_2^{M-2}&\cdots&a_N^{M-2}&0\\
a_1^{M-1}&a_2^{M-1}&\cdots&a_N^{M-1}&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I want to prove that: $\mathrm{rank}(B)=M$. I know that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=M$ and that by attaching a column the rank will definitely not decrease so it may remain the same or increase. I am not comfortable with these types of arguments so what I am saying here might be insufficient for the proof. Any ideas?

Comment: $\text{rank} B=M-1$?Why ? It should be $M$

Comment: @Maths_Is_Fun Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: If the last column of a matrix is $\left(0,0,\ldots,0,1\right)^T$, then the rank of this matrix is $1$ plus the rank of its submatrix obtained by removing the last row and the last column. This is not hard to prove (e.g., consider linear dependence relations between its rows).